# Shallow copy of object referenced array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I want to implement the ICloneable.Clone() function.
My class has some primitive members but also an array of referenced objects.
In this referenced object class, I don´t want to implement this function too, so I´m wondering if it is easily possible to do sth like MemberWise Clone from outside.

```
Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
    Return Me.MemberwiseClone
End Function
```

I have found sth like Array.Clone, but this only works for primitive Types?

Comment: What is the reason for not implementing Clone on the referenced class? You won't be able to call MemberwiseClone on it from outside its inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

```
Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
    Dim copy = Me.MemberwiseClone
    copy.SomeArray = copy.SomeArray.Select(Function(r) r.Clone).ToArray()
    Return copy
End Function
```

Note that since MemberwiseClone is protected, you can't call MemberwiseClone on the objects in the array if those objects are not part of the same inheritance hierarchy as the object implementing this function.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn´t work. If I change a property of the object I want to shallow copy after copying it, both changes, so the reference must still be the same. The only way I make this work is to implement clone()-Method in the array referenced object class and iterate through each objects and clone them.

Comment: Ok- I thought you just wanted to literally copy the array itself instead of the items in the array.  Edited.